# Unable to start activity: invalid int

Tags: java, android

Please guys I am writing this android app, but I'm getting a run time error in the logCat : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    EditText et;
    Button guess, randomize;
    TextView tv1, tv2;

    int num1;
    int num2;
    int userAns;
    int answer;
    final Random rand = new Random();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        guess = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        randomize = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);



        randomize(rand);
        tv2.setText(num1 + " + " + num2);
        userAns = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());

        guess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                answer = num1 + num2;
                if (userAns == answer) {
                    tv1.setText("Correct... The Answer is " +answer);
                } else {
                    tv1.setText("wrong");
                }
            }
        });

        randomize.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                randomize(rand);
            }
        });

    }

    private void randomize(final Random rand) {
        num1 = 1 + rand.nextInt(50);
        num2 = 1 + rand.nextInt(50);
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your Logcat and specify the line you are getting  java.lang.NumberFormatException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

et is empty unless you set it to a default value.  As such, et.getText will return "", which is not a valid number so parseInt will throw an exception.   You need to wait to get that text until the user has pressed the guess button and get it then.

Answer (score 1):

numberFormatException is usually caused by a string to int conversion going wrong. I'm suspecting this line.

```
userAns = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

since it's not initialized with text yet.

wrap it in a try/catch

**EDIT**:
How to fix

I would recommend moving

```
userAns = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
```

inside guess.setOnClickListener like so:

```
guess.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        answer = num1 + num2;

        try {
            userAns = Integer.parseInt(et.getText().toString());
            if (userAns == answer) {
                tv1.setText("Correct... The Answer is " +answer);
            } else {
                tv1.setText("wrong");
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // output error that 'et' field is emtpy or doesnt contain a number
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to avoid the problem?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a fix